# Debian, RaspberryPi, автомонтирование USB дисков NTFS

Tags: debian, usb, raspbian, mount

Всем привет.
В систему установил пакет ntfs-3g.
Создал правило на автомонитрование.

***ACTION=="add" KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]" RUN+="/bin/mount -t auto -o users,rw,conv=binary,dmask=000,fmask=000 /dev/%k /media/%E{ID_VENDOR}_%E{ID_MODEL}_%n"***

Конечно, перезапустил все правила. Подключаю диск, и он монтируется. И даже можно прочитать каталог. Но через пару-тройку секунд  в имени каталога монтирования появляется знак вопроса и в mc он уже отображается красным цветом.

При этом mount рапортует об успешной операции подключения диска:

***/dev/sda1 on /media/_SAMSUNG_HD103SI_1 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)***

Если тоже самое делать руками, каталог работоспособный очень длительное время. И выхлоп mount абсолютно идентичный.

Как можно увидеть, почему отключился каталог или как исправить такое поведение?

PS: абсолютный не линуксист, поэтому прошу поподробней отвечать - многих вещей могу просто не знать.

Comment: начинать стоит с [просмотра записей в кольцевом буфере сообщений программы linux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg), появившихся в промежутке между моментом монтирования и моментом, «когда всё сломалось». далее — анализ логов за тот же промежуток, далее — мониторинг событий udev за тот же промежуток.

Comment: вообще оффтопик, но разница может быть в umask. Попробуй проверитьчто выдает udevadm monitor, Замени вызов mount на скрипт который сохранит  или напишет куда-нибудь параметры , которые ему были фактически заданы правилом, там может быть проблема. По хорошему нужна еще обработка других действий с устройством. Что если его будут пытаться отключить? Есть вот такое https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/

Comment: umаsk добавил, но не помогло. параметры фактически передаются неизменными и mount тоже все это корректно выводит.

Comment: вывод монитора немного помог, но интерпретировать результат не могу. Через две секунды добавились тири строчки:UDEV  [21064.976561] add      /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
KERNEL[21068.033767] change   /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [21068.163541] change   /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)

Comment: подозреваю, что эти changes в KERNEL и является декларацией изменений. Но по какой причине непонятно.

Comment: вывод в /var/syslog следующий: Mar 19 14:02:32 nas01 kernel: [21060.198134] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Mar 19 14:02:32 nas01 kernel: [21060.225341]  sda: sda1
Mar 19 14:02:32 nas01 kernel: [21060.233629] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk

Comment: Mar 19 14:02:38 nas01 ntfs-3g[2038]: Version 2014.2.15AR.2 integrated FUSE 28
Mar 19 14:02:38 nas01 ntfs-3g[2038]: Mounted /dev/sda1 (Read-Write, label "INTENSO", NTFS 3.1)
Mar 19 14:02:38 nas01 ntfs-3g[2038]: Cmdline options: rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,conv=binary,umask=002,dmask=000,fmask=000,users
Mar 19 14:02:38 nas01 ntfs-3g[2038]: Mount options: rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,conv=binary,users,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sda1,blkdev,blksize=4096
Mar 19 14:02:38 nas01 ntfs-3g[2038]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7

Comment: Как можно заметить, последние сообщения идут с 6-ти секундной задержкой.

Comment: dmesg --level=err,warn    :  [ 5629.731252] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[ 5629.731289] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6465.170446] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[ 6465.170482] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6527.902229] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[ 6527.902268] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[21060.189640] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[21060.189686] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through